# How do I DDoS someone and avoid the FBI?

Tags: hacker-experience

Someone got on my server and deleted some files. I decided to retaliate by DDoSing them, destroying their hardware, but apparently this attracted the attention of the FBI. They put a bounty on me, and I was quickly DDoSed by someone else, which made me lose my hardware.

I've since changed my IP to stop the barrage of intrusions, and I'm working on making enough money to buy back some hardware. Is there a way I can safely DDoS another player?

Comment: It's a game - https://hackerexperience.com/

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, I'm sure the NSA agent assigned to this site appreciates the distinction. :)

Comment: I nominate this title for the archives.

Comment: Every time I read this... "Ok, so this is for the game. Is it though? Yes, it is.... *Is it though...?*"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[There is an excellent guide on the HE forums on how not to get on the FBI list.](https://forum.hackerexperience.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=930)  Here I'm going to give you the quick, from-memory version.

- **Heed warnings.**  Although it's possible to jump directly to the FBI list, you are normally flagged by Safenet first.  If you get an email from Safenet warning you that your actions have garnered their attention, *stop* performing high-profile actions immediately.  Do not delete files from other people's servers, attack bank accounts, and especially do not DDoS anyone while Safenet is watching you.  Doing so can earn you a "promotion" from the Safenet list to the FBI list in a hurry.  If you're not sure if you're on the Safenet list, visit them (on the First Whois, look them up) and use your browser's search function to find the first half of your IP.  If it's there, you're being watched.
- **Minimize your damage.**  Don't delete every file on the server, delete the one that matters/hurts the most.  Don't DDoS every person you quarrel with, DDoS one and leave his IP in your logs where it shows you seized him as a warning to the others.  Don't steal five million from that account, steal a half million and pull out.  Try not to do enough damage all at once that you skip straight to the FBI's Most Wanted list without getting your Safenet warning first.
- **Be prepared.**  Don't wait until you're on the FBI list to have your ISP start resetting your IP to protect yourself.  An IP reset takes ten minutes - a DDoS takes five.  If you're going to take high-profile actions, *especially* DDoS'ing someone, queue up the IP reset in advance.  Wait until it is ready to be executed from your Task Manager (if you don't watch it, it won't auto-complete - it will wait for you to give the command) *before* doing something that will put you on the list.  If you end up on the list, you have only 300 seconds - plus the time it takes a bounty hunter to notice you and set up his DDoS, so add ten to sixty seconds - before your hardware will be destroyed.  It should only take you ten seconds to get to your Task Manager and press the button to disappear.  Now lay low until your IP reset cools down (or, if you're stinking rich, don't and just pay the fee), queue up your next one, and *then* you can go big again.  Not before.  If you can't change your IP at a moment's notice, you are *vulnerable*.  If there's more than five minutes left before your IP resets, you can be DDoS'ed and there is very little you can do about it.

TL;DR

> You normally get a **warning** from Safenet before you get on the FBI list.  Stop deleting files, doing illegal bank transfers, and DDoSing people if you get one.
>
> **Don't go overboard.**  Only hit someone as hard as you need to.
>
> Make sure to always **be ready** to escape if you're targeted by a DDoS, by having an IP reset already queued in the Task Manager.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I know what you're talking about, but to make your answer more accessible, could you expand slightly on how you can queue the IP reset to not auto-complete? It would also be great if you could split up your points (particularly your last one) into more digestible chunks.

Comment: Queuing items to not auto-complete is a basic HE skill, it might belong in another question.  (For example, when I'm messing around on another player's server, or just a commonly used NPC server, I queue a "Edit log file" and complete it immediately after I complete another action on that server.)  If you ask it, I'll answer it ^_^ I'll make a TL;DR for my answer shortly.

Comment: TL;DR added ^_^