# How can I earn money with torrents?

Tags: hacker-experience

In hacker Experience, you can make money from torrents. It's really nice to know it is possible but it would be really awesome to know how I can achieve this.

I have in my software list a torrent called "F.L.I.E.N.D.S.torrent". I got it from a player I hacked. But now, I have no idea what to do with it! And it makes a lot of kittens sad D:

How can I make money from torrents? What am I missing?

Comment: for a moment there i thought this was spam...though i dare say a lot of the questions about this game will generate question titles which need context

Comment: @Memor-X yeah, maybe we would need to figure out some title tags for this game

Comment: probably wise to add some context to the title so FBI isn't knocking on your door.

Comment: @Rapitor apparently it's too late for [Schism](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/186351/how-do-i-ddos-someone-and-avoid-the-fbi?rq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to make money from torrents, you need to acquire a `.vwarez` virus. You also need a `.torrent` file on your own server.

Simply upload (and run) the `.vwarez` onto a victim. You'll be asked to select a torrent to use; choose the `.torrent` file on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

The better the version of the warez and the .torrent, the more money you get.  Torrent files can't be developed. There are 3 versions (1.0, 2.0 and 3.0), you can download the .torrent files at torrent´s market, the torrent files stay with you.

The file you need to send to the victim is the .warez virus.

You don't need to send the torrent files to the victim!

The warez virus can be developed and can be hidden.