# Where I can get a "warez" virus?

Tags: hacker-experience

[Inspired by another question.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/186451/how-can-i-earn-money-with-torrents)

I recently left myself vulnerable and got hit hard, and am rebuilding.  I want to earn money with torrents (the attacker didn't delete or hide my FLIENDS torrent), but I can't find the virus I need to get started.  Where can I find this virus, so I can put this torrent to work?

(Note that the HE ToS restricts the sharing of in-game IP addresses.  A "trail" I can follow in game, like the puzzle trail, is probably the best answer, unless a player chooses to expose their own IP, in which case, I thank you for your sacrifice.)

Comment: I found mine while hacking another player, this is probably the best thing you can do to find one. If you are really desperate, just send me a message in the gme and I'll find a way to send you the file. I have the same username as here.

Comment: @TheBird956 Nah, not desperate, just noticed a lot of other people whose systems I was poking around in (probably how I got hit in the first place - wasn't fast enough scrubbing their logs) also had torrents but none of them had the virus, figured the community would benefit from someone asking the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can get a basic warez virus if you follow the trail of the first puzzle. There is a server along the way that has those files.

Comment: This is the same for every piece of software.